# RegEx that matching an expression NOT at the beginning of a line

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I've been pounding my head on an expression for over an hour, without results. So it's time to ask for help.

In the following (multi-line) text:
Waltzes **vol** 15
Waltzes **vol.** 15
Waltzes **vol.** A
Waltzes**, volume** 15
**volume** 15: waltzes

The portions in **bold** are the matches of the RegEx I came up with thus far:
`(?!^),*\s*(?:vol[ume]*\.*)\s*(?=[0-9A-Z]+)`

All are correct, except the last one, which should not be included because it is at the beginning of a line.
As far I can tell from the docs at http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html, the `(?!^)` look-around part in the expression should exclude matches found by `,*\s*(?:vol[ume]*\.*)\s*(?=[0-9A-Z]+)` at the beginning of a line, but that doesn't seem to work.

On the other hand, the expression `(?!^)op[us]*\.*\s*(?=[0-9]+)` works correctly and does not return a match in the last line of the following text:
Waltzes **op.** 15
Waltzes **opus** 15
opus 15: waltzes

What am I doing wrong with the first expression?

Comment: Your second regex does match the "opus" on the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why your regex isn't working as expected

- The negative lookbehind is missing `<`. It should be `(?<!^)`
- The lookbehind should precede `(?:vol[ume]*\.*)` immediately
- You need to enable multi-line `(?m)` (without which `^` would only match start of input)

So, your regex with these corrections becomes

```
(?m),*\s*(?<!^)(?:vol[ume]*\.*)\s*(?=[0-9A-Z]+)
```

The above works but can be further improved. The use of `[ume]*` would also let matches like `voleee`, `volmeu` etc. Instead of being unbounded with `*`, `,` and `.` can be made optional with `?`.

```
(?m),?\s*(?<!^)(?:vol\.?|volume)\s*(?=[0-9A-Z]+)
```

Comment: This solution does exactly what I need. Thanks for pointing out the misuse of `*` in favor of `?`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to match vol/vol./volume that is not at the beginning of a line, the following should work:

```
^.+(vol\.?|volume)
```

`^.+` means match 1 or more characters from the beginning of the line

`(vol\.?|volume)` means match `vol` followed by an optional `.` or match `volume`

Answer (score 0):

Go with it, instead of fighting it:

```
^.+\s*(?:vol[ume]*\.*)\s*(?=[0-9A-Z]+)
```

Force a match at the beginning of the line (`^`), followed by *one or more* characters...

Comment: Would also match "voleee", "volmeu" etc.

Comment: Understood.  Because the full requirements are not stated (yes, to some level they can be inferred from the regex) I was addressing only the specific question.

Comment: This solution selects everything from the beginning of the line up to and including vol. or volume, which does not match the requirement in my original question.